# How can I make MongoDB treat "ł" like "l", as synonym?

Tags: java, mongodb, character-encoding

I have a problem with character polish in *MongoDB*. For example I have the word: `"śliwka"` and when I use full search, MongoDB automatically converts that word to `"sliwka"`, but if I want to search for the word `"łukasz"` MongoDB didnt convert it to `"lukasz"`.

How can I make MongoDB treat `ł` and `l` like same character?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library to create Synonyms in MongoDB:

https://github.com/seelio/mongoose-synonyms

Usage

> After defining your schema, load the plugin with the dictionary to use
>   for each field:

```
var mongooseSynonyms = require('mongoose-synonyms');
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
MySchema.plugin(mongooseSynonyms, {
  dictionary: 'nicknames',
  fields: ['firstName', '$text.$search']
});
```

> The keyOnly makes sure that each term will be replaced by the
>   dictionary key only, thus avoiding all possible synonyms. For example,
>   the for the following dictionary entry:

```
dictionary["łukasz"] = ["lukasz"];
```

or

```
dictionary["ł"] = ["l"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it :)

Comment: How can I inject dependency to Java Language ? I don't want to connect with MongoDB via JS because this option for me is very dangerous:)